# How to save a user preference within an excel add-in?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, settings

I have written an excel add-in that queries an external csv file.  The user enters the search parameters into a cell formula in the spreadsheet, and the formula cleanly retrieves the specific data point and outputs it into the cell.

I'm trying to design a self-contained add-in that will work for many different clients/customers, each of whom has their own set of users, network and IT infrastructure.  My question concerns linking the add-in with the appropriate filepath of the .csv, which may change from time to time.

I'm trying to avoid having to manually enter a filepath upon installation of the .csv, to allow for flexibility to change the path later without reinstalling.  My initial thinking is to have a button on the ribbon that lets the user choose the filepath via browsing.  However, I'm not sure how to make that filepath choice 'permanent' so that it isn't lost upon closing and restarting Excel.  So, essentially, I want to have the user be able to save the filepath as a 'preference' that endures, without needing to touch the developer tab, which many find to be overwhelming and scary.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel add-in is nothing else as workbook. You can store data inside it.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserData").Range("A1") = sPathToToCsvFile
ThisWorkbook.Save 'to saves data for further use
```

Comment: I would actually recommend making it a named range, but yes. This.

Comment: Good advice, RubberDuck!

Comment: Thanks Maciej! At the risk of being chatty, feel free to stop by the [CR VBA chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba) sometime.

Comment: Thanks for invitation ;)

Comment: Upvoted. Another option is to use `SaveSetting` and `GetSetting` to write/read from the registry (with a "restore" option to delete any saved settings)

Comment: @brettdj, It's true (upvoted), but there is a bit problem. User can have no access to registry, because of OS rights/privileges.

Comment: @brettdj Oh my goodness, I never knew about this functionality! I've encountered an issue where my add-in cannot be saved due to the location it sits in, so this is a huge lifesaver! Thank you!!